# Order Validation failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, backend

I have a problem with error validation [image]

- orderController.js :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    orderItems: [
        {
            name: {type: String, required: true},
            qty: {type: Number, required: true},
            image: {type: String, required: true},
            price: {type: Number, required: true},
            product: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: 'Product'
            }
        }
],
    shippingAddress: {
        address: { type: String, required: true },
        city: { type: String, required: true },
        postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
        country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    paymentResult: {
       id: {type: String },
       status: {type: String },
       update_time: {type: String },
       email_address: {type: String },
    }, 
    taxPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid:{
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
        type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
        type: Date,
    },
},
{
    timestamps: true,
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

- orderRoutes.js:

```
import express from "express";
import {
 addOrderItems
} from '../controllers/orderController.js';
import {protect} from '../middleware/authMiddleware.js';


const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').post(protect, addOrderItems);

export default router;
```

- ShippingScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import FormContainer from '../../components/FormContainer'
import CheckoutSteps from '../../components/CheckoutSteps'
import { saveShippingAddress } from '../../actions/cartActions'

const ShippingScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const navigate  = useNavigate()
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const { shippingAddress } = cart

  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address || '');
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city || '');
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(
    shippingAddress.postalCode || ''
  );
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country || '');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(saveShippingAddress({ address, city, postalCode, country }))
    navigate('/payment')
  }

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 />
      <h1>Shipping</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId='address'>
          <Form.Label htmlFor='address'>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter address'
            value={address}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='city'>
          <Form.Label htmlFor='city'>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter city'
            value={city}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='postalCode'>
          <Form.Label htmlFor='postalCode'>PostalCode</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter postal code'
            value={postalCode}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='country'>
          <Form.Label htmlFor='country'>Country</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter country'
            value={country}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Link to='/cart'>
            <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
                Back
            </Button>
        </Link>
        <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
          Continue
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  )
}

export default ShippingScreen
```

What do I need to change to avoid the error and complete the order?
If I remove the field 'required' from every field in shippingAddress in orderModel.js it's functions.
Could it depend on the model?
Since yesterday I have been stuck on this point and I don't know what to do anymore.

- saveShippingAddress in cartActions.js:

```
export const saveShippingAddress = (data) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  
    localStorage.setItem('shippingAddress', JSON.stringify(data))
  }
```

The problem is in orderModel.js because after shippingAddress there are {} only while I must use [] also.

I solved.

Comment: Can you show the code for the action `saveShippingAddress`? Is this a backend error (response to a request going out) or does your client-side validation display the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same error has  occured to me . you should check if the name(shippingAddress) in Model order.js  is same as dispatched shippingaddress(name) .they gotta same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).